# Use jQuery to check for number of options NOT selected in a multiselect

Tags: jquery, multi-select

I have a multiselect that has a huge list and I'm not allowed to have an option that just says "All".

But in the background I still want to do a check to see if all are selected or not.
I saw/had some snippet of code that did this before but I can't find it. What I remember it doing is checking to see if the number of options NOT selected was equal to 0, then you knew all the options were selected.

I want to do a check like this on one line if I can:

```
$("#my-multiselect:not(:selected)").length === 0
```

But `$("#my-multiselect:not(:selected)").length` is only returning 1 or 0 like a true or false I imagine. Am I using the `:not()` incorrectly? Or what else do I need to do to get an exact count?

Comment: Because you are using `id` attribute, use `class` for multiple elements.

Comment: Really? But I only want to check it for this one particular multiselect, not all or just any on the page.

Comment: Maybe `$("#my-multiselect :not(:selected)")` (note the space)

Comment: The space worked while still using the id! Thanks!

Comment: Not checkboxes, they are multiselects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a space:

```
$("#my-multiselect :not(:selected)").length === 0
```

Because you want to select the `options` inside `#my-multiselect` element.

Comment: Because the first correct answer. Thanks! Still confuses me though because all examples I've seen do't have a space, so I never tried it.

Comment: The space mean that, for example, having `A B` you will select any `B` that are inside `A`. In that case `$("#my-multiselect :not(:selected)")` is equivalent to `$("#my-multiselect option:not(:selected)")`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are checking the "selected" status of the `<select>` element. But only the `<option>` elements *contained* by the `<select>` element can be "[selected](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option#attr-selected)" -- not the `<select>` element itself.

To count all of the unselected `<option>` elements *within* your `<select>` element, use:

```
$("select#my-multiselect option:not(:selected)").length
```

See my demonstration, below:

```js
$(function() {

  var $button=$('button#calculate'),
      $output=$('p#output');
  
  $button.on('click', function() {
    var unselected = $("select#my-multiselect option:not(:selected)").length;
    $output.text(unselected + " options unselected.");
  });

});
```

```css
select#my-multiselect {
  width:60px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple id="my-multiselect">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Four</option>
  <option value="5">Five</option>
</select>

<button id="calculate">Calculate</button>

<p id="output"><p>
```